# NSPredicate on Array of Custom Object that contains another array of Custom Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

I have an array of objects called **Student**. Where every **Student** have another array of objects called **Subject**. Now I want to filter my Array of students with **Subject Name**. Example of Object is below:

```
@interface Student : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger studentId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString  *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString  *class;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString  *section;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray   *arraySubject;

@end
```

Where **ArraySubject** contains array of objects "Subject"

```
@interface Subject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger subjectId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString  *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString  *languageMedium;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString  *creditHours;

@end
```

What I want is to provide the "Subject Name" and filter my array of Students with that subject Name.

I hope I clears my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use `ANY` for that.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY arraySubject.name = %@", subjectName];
NSArray *filterArray = [studentArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

You can also use `CONTAINS[c]` if you doesn't want to match the exact subjectName with subject.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY arraySubject.name CONTAINS[c] %@", subjectName];
```

Comment: @AzeemAkram Welcome mate :)